# Typescript function type to be either object or string depending on success or failure

Tags: typescript

I have a function that returns a Promise on success or a string on error.

```
async create(createDebtorDto: CreateDebtorDto): Promise<Debtor> {
    console.log("createDebtorDto", createDebtorDto)
    try{
      const createdDebtor = new this.debtorModel(createDebtorDto);
      return await createdDebtor.save();
    }catch(err){
      console.log('err', err)
        return `Unable to create debtor ${err}`;
    }
  }
```

When I try transpile this code, I get the following error:

`src/debtors/debtors.service.ts(19,5): error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Debtor'.`

It seems as though I need to say that the function returns a Promise or a String but that seems to void the point of having static typing.

Can I say on success, return a promise, on error return a string?

Comment: Are you sure you want to `return 'Unable to ...'` as `Debtor` in case of a failure…?

Comment: ^^ ...because in general it's better to let the caller respond to the error as appropriate, rather than conflating success and failure. That's why promises have both resolution *and* rejection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* tell it that the result may be either of those types:

```
: Promise<Debtor | string>
```

But actually, the pattern people expect is that they will handle the error properly:

```
async create(createDebtorDto: CreateDebtorDto): Promise<Debtor> {
    console.log("createDebtorDto", createDebtorDto)
    try {
        const createdDebtor = new this.debtorModel(createDebtorDto);
        return await createdDebtor.save();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('err', err)
        throw `Unable to create debtor ${err}`;
    }
}
```

And called thus:

```
myInstance.create(dto).then((debtor) => {
    // do something with debtor...
}).catch((error) => {
    alert(error);
});
```

This way, you don't need to check the type of debtor within the resolve handler - and it won't cause surprises for people used to dealing with async / promises.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your function always returns a `Promise` because the catch is after an `await` it is dependent on an async value, and `async` methods always need to return a promise anyway. You need to return a `Promise<Debtor| string>` because the result of your async operation is either a `string` (in case of an error) or a `Debtor` in case of success.

```
async create(createDebtorDto: CreateDebtorDto): Promise<Debtor| string> {
    console.log("createDebtorDto", createDebtorDto)
    try{
        const createdDebtor = new this.debtorModel(createDebtorDto);
        return await createdDebtor.save();
    }catch(err){
        console.log('err', err)
        return `Unable to create debtor ${err}`;
    }
}
```

**Note** Returning a string in case of error seems like bad design, you might consider throwing an exception and catching it in the caller.

```
async create(createDebtorDto: CreateDebtorDto): Promise<Debtor> {
    console.log("createDebtorDto", createDebtorDto)
    try{
        const createdDebtor = new this.debtorModel(createDebtorDto);
        return await createdDebtor.save();
    }catch(err){
        console.log('err', err)
        throw `Unable to create debtor ${err}`;
    }
}
```